# Find random images from http://i.imgur.com/

Tags: code-golf, random, internet

[image: Imgur logo]

Imgur is a free image hosting service. Many people use it. Here is an example of an imgur link: https://i.stack.imgur.com/II8CA.png. Write a program that continually outputs random (valid) imgur links. For example, here is some sample output of my progam (not shown because it contains some tricks you will have to figure out yourself):

```
http://i.imgur.com/uFmsA.png
http://i.imgur.com/FlpHS.png
http://i.imgur.com/eAbsZ.png
http://i.imgur.com/lEUsq.png
http://i.imgur.com/RuveH.png
http://i.imgur.com/BoEwB.png
http://i.imgur.com/HVFGQ.png
http://i.imgur.com/PZpMg.png
http://i.imgur.com/DezCY.png
```

Helpful hints:

- When imgur was new, 5-letter links were used.
- When imgur was new, numbers weren't used.
- You can use this to your advantage: only find 5-letter link images with only letters. That is what my program does.
- Also, all images are saved as `.png`.

Requirements:

- Continually output random imgur links
- Links considered sufficiently "random" if 50 are outputted with no repeats
- When visited, links must be an image
- Links must start with `http://i.imgur.com/` and end with `.png`
- Score is amount of characters

I did it in Java (TERRIBLE for golfing) in 452 chars. Not shown here because it contains some tricks you will have to figure out for yourself!)

Comment: Wait, is your definition of random that the output shouldn't contain repeats?

Comment: **Warning:** pornographic images may be present on imgur! =:o

Comment: Are all 5-letter image valid?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### PHP 5.4, 76 characters

URLs are generated in sequential order using only uppercase letters and never repeat, meeting the letter of the specification.

```
<?for($t=@ZZZZ;$t++;)file($u="http://i.imgur.com/$t.png")[0]>@F&&print"$u
";
```

Answer (score 5):

**HTML (152)**

```
<img src=x
onload=console.log(s);g()
onerror=g=function(){s='http://i.imgur.com/'+Math.random().toString(36).substr(2,6)+'.png';event.target.src=s};g()>
```

This logs all found images on the JavaScript console using `console.log()`. Works in all tested browsers (Firefox, Chrome, IE9, Safari and Opera).

The fun part is that all sorts of funny images are flashing up for the blink of an eye :).

[Try it!](http://jsfiddle.net/zR4AS/show/) (jsFiddle wraps this into a more complete HTML page, but browsers also accept the single element.)

Props to the [amazing random string method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1349404/generate-a-string-of-5-random-characters-in-javascript/8084248#8084248) by [doubletap](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1040319/doubletap)!

**Where can I see the JavaScript console and the logged images?**

- *Firefox:* Press Control-Shift-K (Command-Option-K on the Mac). Unselect the Net, CSS and JS buttons there, only select the Logging button.
- *Opera:* Press Control+Shift+i, select the Console tab.
- *Chrome:* Press Control+Shift+i, select the Console tab. On the bottom, select Logs.
- *Safari:* Basically like Chrome, but make sure first that [Safari's developer tools are activated](http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/AppleApplications/Conceptual/Safari_Developer_Guide/1Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007874-CH1-SW4). Then press Control+Alt+C (on Windows, not sure on the Mac) instead of Control+Shift+i, select the Console tab. On the bottom, select Logs.
- *IE:* Press F12, select the console tab.

Comment: This does not meet the requirements. Many of the images it pops up are not valid.

Comment: What do you mean by "not valid"? In the console, only images that could be successfully displayed are logged (see my updated description).

Comment: Oh, okay. Retrying now. Edit: Chrome seems to be logging the invalid images as well.

Comment: Chrome by default mixes error messages and logs. At the bottom of the console tab you have All, Errors, Warnings, Logs. If an image could not be loaded, it displays a 404 error with the image URL. If you select Logs, then only the output generated by my code should display.

Comment: A lot of the logged image URLs just return the [standard imgur error image](http://i.imgur.com/nosuch.png) that says "The image you are requesting does not exist or is no longer available."  I suppose one could argue that those are still valid results under the rules as given, since the returned document _is_ an image.

Comment: @IlmariKaronen Yes, the standard error images are still valid. They **are** technically an image.

Answer (score 4):

### Perl (93 + 4 = 97)

Using imgur's own [random](https://imgur.com/gallery/random) mechanism to get **their** image URLs, which aren't png URLs most of the time:

```
$ perl -Mojo -E 'say+g("http://imgur.com/gallery/random")->dom->at("[rel=image_src]")->attrs("href")for+1..50'
http://i.imgur.com/7cNoA.jpg
...
```

(You need [Mojolicious](http://mojolicio.us) for this.)

Comment: That's brilliant, and so not fair!

Comment: @elssar That's right, at least your second point. ;)

Comment: Oh, that's clever :)

Answer (score 3):

## Perl (87)

```
perl -pe's/\W//g;$_="http://i.imgur.com/$_.png\n";$_=""if`curl $_`=~/^</'</dev/urandom
```

Finding images with uppercase, lowercase and digits from 0 up to any characters,
some day.

Comment: Hehehe, urandom

Answer (score 3):

#### *Mathematica*, 108

White-space added.

```
While[True,
 Import@# /. _Image :> Print@# &[
  "http://i.imgur.com/" <> "a" ~CharacterRange~ "z" ~RandomChoice~ 5 <> ".png"
 ]
]
```

Answer (score 2):

### Python (<s>174</s> <s>158</s> 156)

I want shorter module names in Python. Also an easier method of getting random letters. :)

```
import urllib,random
while 1:a='http://i.imgur.com/%s.png'%''.join(chr(random.randint(65,90))for i in'AAAAA');print('File'not in urllib.urlopen(a).read())*a
```

Explanation:

The modulus operator on a string is the formatting command, in this case it replaces '%s' in the string with 5 random uppercase letters
`a` is the website name (type `str`) 
`('File'not in urllib.urlopen(a).read())` is True when 'File' (from 'File not found!') is **not** found in the the HTML of the URL. (type `bool`) 
`bool` * `str` = `str` if `bool` = True, so it will only output `a` if 'File' is not found in the HTML code.

Comment: What part of the spec says you have to use both upper and lower case letters? `chr(random.randint(65,90))`

Comment: I ran it and it didn't output anything. Nice trick with `'File'` though :)

Comment: @PeterTaylor: :) I didn't know that there were any links on imgur with only uppercase letters, but I guess that would be obvious enough. Thanks!

Comment: @Doorknob: It outputs a newline unless a link is found, then it will give a link.

Comment: Any sequence of length 5 will work for your 5 random characters, so you can shave a few characters off by using something like `'XXXXX'` rather than `range(5)`. This also has the advantage of not requiring whitespace between it and the `in`.

Comment: @Strigoides: `Links considered sufficiently "random" if 50 are outputted with no repeats`?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. My point is, you're using `for i in range(5)` to repeat `chr(random.randint(65,90))` 5 times. Since you don't actually use `i`, you can replace `range(5)` with any sequence of length 5, right?

Comment: @Strigoides: I thought you meant iterating through 'AAAAA' to 'ZZZZZ'. Now I understand, that's pretty clever. :) Thanks!

Comment: You can shave 2 chars if you import both the modules as a single character variable.

Comment: @elssar: It's the same length, I think. `random as r` `r` is the same length as `random` `random`.

Comment: Oh right, I didn't account for the `r`

Answer (score 2):

## Python, <strike>361</strike> <strike>355</strike> <strike>334</strike> <strike>332</strike> <strike>322</strike> 314 characters

A little obfuscated, nothing too difficult. May result in unusually high density of cat pictures, you have been warned.

```
import json as j,urllib as o,time as t;a=0
while 1:
 q="i.imgur";y,p=('data','children');r="njj";h="erqqvg.pbz/";u="uggc://"+h+"e/"+r;c=j.loads(o.urlopen(u.decode('rot13')+".json?sorted=new&after=%s"%a).read())[y]
 for s in c[p]:
  f=s[y];w=f['url'].strip('?1')
  if w.find(q)!=-1:print w
 a=c['after'];t.sleep(3)
```

Output:

```
http://i.imgur.com/u3vyMCW.jpg
http://i.imgur.com/zF7rPAf.jpg
http://i.imgur.com/aDTl7OM.jpg
http://i.imgur.com/KONVsYw.jpg
http://i.imgur.com/RVM2pYi.png
http://i.imgur.com/tkMhc9T.jpg
http://i.imgur.com/KxUrZkp.gif
http://i.imgur.com/mnDTovy.jpg
http://i.imgur.com/WpuXbHb.jpg
http://i.imgur.com/qZA3mCR.jpg
http://i.imgur.com/AxMS1Fs.png
http://i.imgur.com/TLSd571.jpg
http://i.imgur.com/VfMhLIQ.jpg
http://i.imgur.com/Wu32582.jpg
http://i.imgur.com/hrmQL2F.jpg
http://i.imgur.com/Clg8N.jpg
http://i.imgur.com/7Wsko.jpg
http://i.imgur.com/Rhb0UNx.jpg
http://i.imgur.com/LAXAf45.gif
http://i.imgur.com/jhOLJ9B.jpg
http://i.imgur.com/FQ9NeAl.jpg
http://i.imgur.com/oqzf6tE.jpg
http://i.imgur.com/rnpXs1A.jpg
http://i.imgur.com/DfUIz6k.jpg
http://i.imgur.com/orfGA5I.jpg
http://i.imgur.com/wBT7JNt.jpg
http://i.imgur.com/RycK1m2.jpg
http://i.imgur.com/7j21FIR.jpg
http://i.imgur.com/z2tVnNC.jpg
http://i.imgur.com/mnsAGuF.jpg
http://i.imgur.com/vIZM1NY.jpg
http://i.imgur.com/JT3XRI4.jpg
http://i.imgur.com/SNpwTmp.jpg
http://i.imgur.com/u9ynLb9.jpg
http://i.imgur.com/DrFWsBP.jpg
http://i.imgur.com/rU6oyup.jpg
http://i.imgur.com/XxBD5nl.jpg
http://i.imgur.com/d09qQzP.jpg
http://i.imgur.com/vvPSbqI.jpg
http://i.imgur.com/1hdfobQ.jpg
http://i.imgur.com/4LLC6Vs.jpg
http://i.imgur.com/RfasxO2.jpg
http://i.imgur.com/BBcpOos.jpg
http://i.imgur.com/zMH8mgG.jpg
http://i.imgur.com/7g8k2Ww.jpg
```

Comment: All the images... are animals? There is some trickery going on here :P +1 because I like the cute animals :3

Answer (score 2):

## Bash <strike>(129, 121)</strike> (117, 109)

I've got two versions: an iterative and an endless recursive one (which will slowly eat up all memory).
Both versions check if there actually is a PNG file present (jpg's, gif's and other file types are ignored).

Iterative(old) (129):

```
while true;do u=http://i.imgur.com/$(tr -dc a-zA-Z</dev/urandom|head -c5).png;curl $u -s 2>&1|head -c4|grep PNG$ -q&&echo $u;done
```

Recursive(old) (121):

```
:(){ u=http://i.imgur.com/$(tr -dc a-zA-Z</dev/urandom|head -c5).png;curl $u -s 2>&1|head -c4|grep PNG$ -q&&echo $u;:;};:
```

**Note**:
There might be a compatability issue with grep. My grep manual states that `-s` silents grep's output but it does nothing. However, using `--quiet`, `--silent` or `-q` instead works.

**EDIT:**

Using content headers now after reading https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/10499/7195 :)

Iterative (117):

```
while true;do u=http://i.imgur.com/$(tr -dc a-zA-Z</dev/urandom|head -c5).png;curl $u -sI|grep image -q&&echo $u;done
```

Recursive (109):

```
:(){ u=http://i.imgur.com/$(tr -dc a-zA-Z</dev/urandom|head -c5).png;curl $u -sI|grep image -q&&echo $u;:;};:
```

Answer (score 1):

### R, 182 characters

```
library(httr);while(0<1){s=paste("http://i.imgur.com/",paste(sample(c(LETTERS,letters),5),collapse=""),".png",sep="");if(HEAD(s)$headers$'content-type'=='text/html')'' else print(s)}
```

Answer (score 1):

## Python, 153 chars

```
import string as s,random as w,requests as r
while 1:
 t='http://i.imgur.com/%s.png'%''.join(w.sample(s.letters,5))
 if'not'not in r.get(t).text:print t
```

While this works, it is bloody slow and might take many seconds before returning any output.

Inspired by @beary605's solution - he saved me a bunch of characters as I was planning to check for image by content-type header.

Comment: `random.sample` :) That is a much better way of choosing characters.

Comment: Yep, amazing what Code golf will force you to Google, and learn.

Answer (score 1):

## Ruby (103 chars)

```
require"open-uri";loop{u="http://i.imgur.com/#{rand(1e9).to_s(36)[0,5]}.png";open u rescue next;puts u}
```

Comment: You have to add a `.png` to the end of the URL.

Comment: @Doorknob: Whoops, fixed

Answer (score 1):

## Bash/command-line tools, 72 chars

Borrowing @memowe's [clever technique](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/10503/11259):

```
curl -sL http://imgur.com/gallery/random|grep e_sr|cut -d\" -f4;exec $0
```

This achieves a continuous loop by re-execing itself within the same process space.

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jellylanguage), 41 bytes

```
ØẠẊs5Ḣ
“http://i.imgur.com/”;¢;“.png”ṄƲÐḶ
```

How?

```
ØẠẊs5Ḣ  : Helper Link
ØẠ      : Upper and Lowercase Alphabet
  Ẋ     : Shuffle
   s5   : Split Into Lengths of 5
     Ḣ  : Head; pop from front of list
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
“http://i.imgur.com/”;¢;“.png”ṄƲÐḶ  : Main Link
“http://i.imgur.com/”               : String Literal
                      ¢             : Previous link as a nilad.
                        “.png”      : String Literal
                     ; ;            : Concat
                              Ṅ     : Print with a linefeed
                               Ʋ    : Last four links as a monad
                                ÐḶ  : Loop; Repeat until the results are no longer unique.
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m700KzUnp3LBgqWlJWm6FjftD894uGvBw11dxaYPdyzietQwJ6OkpMBKXz9TLzM3vbRILzk_V_9Rw1zrQ4usgZJ6BXnpQN7DnS3HNh2e8HDHtiXFScnFUMNghgIA)